How to get a `ITestOutputHelper` in a `IClassFixture`?
Using xUnit with asp.net, I have isolated some test dependencies in different fixtures that should be global (they perform test setup that can be shared among multiple tests); but on more than one occasion I needed to write some logs on those fixtures to debug certain situations.
A sample is:
public class UnitTest(InterestingFixture f): IClassFixture<InterestingFixture> {
    [Fact]
    public void Test() {
       var data = f.GetData();
       // do something with data...
    }
}

public class InterestingFixture {
  public InterestingFixture() {
    // performs some initialization which I want to log to the test output
  }
}

In the same above, I want InterestingFixture to get an instance of ITestOutputHelper so that I can write something to the output. I've tried adding ITestOutputHelper to its constructor, but it seems that xUnit isn't injecting anything on the IClassFixtures.
I could manually instantiate InterestingFixture, but it will remove the singleton properties given by xUnit.
How can I accomplish that? Is it supported by xUnit?
I'm on xUnit 2.8.

Not sure if this is exactly what you are trying to accomplish but, your fixture class could store the logs and let your test class print them. Like so:
public class TestFixture : IAsyncLifetime
{
    private readonly StringBuilder _sb = new();
    public string Logs => _sb.ToString();

    public Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        _sb.AppendLine("Initialising...");

        // do something

        _sb.AppendLine("Success!");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task DisposeAsync() => Task.CompletedTask;
}

public class UnitTest : IClassFixture<TestFixture>
{
    private readonly TestFixture _fixture;
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper _output;

    public UnitTest(TestFixture fixture, ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        _fixture = fixture;
        _output = output;

        _output.WriteLine(_fixture.Logs);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        // your test
    }
}


That's an interesting work around. Not as effective as printing as it goes, but I may adapt it to my needs. Thanks!

To print as it goes you could have a method in your fixture that takes the ITestOutputHelper and have your test class calling it in the constructor, or at the beginning of the test cases if async. This lazy initialisation of your fixture should only happen once for all your test so, wrap the initialisation of your expensive object with a lock (or a double-checked lock).

In my fixture I'm using a custom implementation of ITestOutputHelper:
    public class BufferedTestOutputHelper : ITestOutputHelper
    {
        private readonly object _lock = new();
        public StringBuilder Buffer { get; } = new();

        public void WriteLine(string message)
        {
            lock (_lock) {
                // send to all subscribers
                _subscriptions.ForEach(o => o.Subscriber.WriteLine(message));

                if (Buffer.Length > 0) Buffer.AppendLine();
                Buffer.Append(message);
            }
        }

        public void WriteLine(string format, params object[] args)
        {
            lock (_lock) {
                // send to all subscribers
                _subscriptions.ForEach(o => o.Subscriber.WriteLine(format, args));

                if (Buffer.Length > 0) Buffer.AppendLine();
                Buffer.AppendFormat(format, args);
            }
        }

        private readonly List<BufferedTestOutputHelperSubscription> _subscriptions = [];

        public IDisposable Subscribe(ITestOutputHelper subscriber)
        {
            var subscription = new BufferedTestOutputHelperSubscription(this, subscriber);

            lock (_lock) {
                _subscriptions.Add(subscription);
                subscriber.WriteLine(Buffer.ToString());
            }

            return subscription;
        }

        private class BufferedTestOutputHelperSubscription : IDisposable
        {
            private readonly BufferedTestOutputHelper _owner;
            public ITestOutputHelper Subscriber { get; }

            public BufferedTestOutputHelperSubscription(
                BufferedTestOutputHelper owner,
                ITestOutputHelper subscriber)
            {
                _owner = owner;
                Subscriber = subscriber;
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                lock (_owner._lock) {
                    _owner._subscriptions.Remove(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }

Example of a fixture:
public class MyFixture : IDisposable
{
    public BufferedTestOutputHelper Output { get; set; }

    public MyFixture()
    {
        Output = new BufferedTestOutputHelper();
        Output.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Output.WriteLine("Bye, World!");
    }
}

Using of that fixure in Test:
public class MyTest : IClassFixture<MyFixture>, IDisposable
{
    private readonly MyFixture _fixture;
    private readonly IDisposable _outputSubscription;

    public MyTest(
        ITestOutputHelper output,
        MyFixture fixture)
    {
        _fixture = fixture;
        _outputSubscription = fixture.Output.Subscribe(output);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        _fixture.Output.WriteLine("Test1");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _outputSubscription.Dispose();
    }
}

In this case I'm using subscription, because sometime it happend, that my fixture called "WriteLine" and the output of xUnit is already disposed.
And "Bye, World!" is not written to the output because the subscription is closed before in test.
